# Using Jenkins to run SonarQube against any Project and choice of branche(s)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am working on creating a single Jenkins job that allows you to pick the GitHub project and then select the branch you would like to run your SonarQube tests on.

So far I have been able to create a job that ONLY runs against the Master build of each project.

Does anyone have any experience creating something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parametrize your build. 
You will have to make gitproject and gitBranch as a parameter this will make you select the project you want to run and select the branch too. Here is an example

```
pipeline {
  agent {
        node { 
            label any
        }
    }
    parameters {
            choice(
                name: 'PLATFORM',
                choices:"Test\nArt19-Data-Pipeline\nBrightcove-Report\nBrightcove-Video\nData-Delivery\nGlobal_Facebook_Engagement_Score\nGoogle-Analytics-Data-Pipeline\nInstagram-Data-Pipeline\nTwitter-Analytics\nTwitter-Data-Pipeline\nYoutube-Data",
                description: "Choose the lambda function to deploy or rollback")
            choice(
                name: 'STAGE',
                choices:"dev\nstag",
                description: "Choose the lambda function to deploy or rollback")    
    }
  stages {
    stage("Git CheckOut") {
      steps {
        //CheckOut from the repository
        //git credentialsId: 'svc.gitlab',branch:'master', url: 'git@git.yourProjectURL/yourProjectName.git'
                echo " Parameters are ${PLATFORM}"
                echo " STAGE IS ${STAGE}"
      }
    }


    }
}
```

All you need is replace the 'master' with a a paramter and the 'yourProjectName' with another paramter instead of the one i used as example

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: thanks for the response! Do you know of a dynamic way to do this where if we were to add new branches it would automatically populate the drop down?

Comment: you can do it using array and loops but that will be too much work. My suggestion is you dont even need a dropdown. You can make it as a regulat parameter. So basicically when you enter branch name (assuming you know the branch you are trying to build) it will checkout that branch . its simple

Comment: That would work too! I wanted to the constant updating and cleanups. Thanks for the suggestions @mbn217!!

Comment: If the solution was helpful, consider marking the answer as useful by clicking on the"^" button, so other can see it. Thanks